# SQL subquery error 1054 unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the following code I get this error message:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'myvaluealerts.symbols.metadada' in 'field list'

I have read several posts similar to this one but since this is my first experience using query code for a SQL database I don't fully understand all the replies I've read.  What I have read so far has helped me improve this code to where I'm only getting this error (instead of the many others I've fixed).

I have an SQL  database named `myvaluealerts` containing three tables named
`symbols`, `users`, and `payments`.   I'm only using the `symbols` table with this query.

I'm trying to read a single field of data related to user 28, and paste it in the same field for user 37.  The column "metadata" is comma separated text.

```
Update `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`metadata` ,  
(
   Select `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`metadata`
   From `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`
   Where `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`user_id` = 28 and 
     `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`symbol` = 'XOM'
) output

Set `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`metadata` = `output`.`metadata`
Where `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`user_id` = 37  and 
      `myvaluealerts`.`symbols`.`symbol` = 'XOM'
```

;

thanks,  Dustin

Comment: seems you have missed  a d . `myvaluealerts`.`symbols` `metadata` .. i have updated  you question for this .. and if the code you posted was the r original one .. this can be tha reason of your error

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I must have accidently removed deleted a 'd' in metadata.  I have copied and pasted the code above and now get a syntax error 1064 on line 1.

Comment: Gordon: it appears to be MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your query using table aliases.  You seem to have some bad table references, but I think this is what you want:

```
Update myvaluealerts.symbols s37 join 
       myvaluealerts.symbols s28
       on s28.user_id = 28 and s28.symbol = 'XOM'
    Set s37.metadata = s28.metadata
Where s37.user_id = 37  and 
      s37.symbol = 'XOM'
```

Comment: that worked.  you have a tick in row 5 afters useri_id I had to remove.  but it worked.  Thanks so much.  unfortunately i don't understand what the "s" is about.  I'll have to do some homework.  thanks again